# VB6 calls WPF but after a minute or so it shutdown, help needed

Tags: wpf, vb6

Here where I work we have a VB6 application. 
Slowly this application has to be build to C#. 
From this VB6 application a VB6 form is called and because we need te rebuild this VB6 form, I want to use WPF (C#).

I build an C# interface and a class implementation of this interface. 
This class has a Main method and this starts the WPF view by doing a view.ShowDialog(). 
The WPF is an different project so I only have to register the AA.dll and AA.tlb when the interface/class is changed.

This view.ShowDialog() works fine, the WPF view shows up, but after a minute or so the VB6 application stops working and MS Visual Basic is shutdown. I don't know why.

Used code in VB6 is:

```
Dim objAA As AA.clsAA
        Set objAA = New AA.clsAA

    With objAA          
        Call .Main
    End With
```

Used code in C# is:

```
public void Main()
    {
        var vm = new AaVm();
        var view = new AaView(vm);
        view.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Does somebody now how to help with this issue?

Comment: I don't have much VB6 experience, but `view.ShoDialog()` is a blocking method, meaning that Main will only return when the dialog is closed. My guess would be that the VB6 system does not really like this blocking call. Could you try using `view.Show()` instead and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Only Show() didn't help, and introduced a new probleem. The user can click on the form where he/she came from with Show() and that isn't allowed.
BTW I have isolate this piece of code in a simple VB6 project and then it works. It doens't shutdown, so there must be something in the real application that triggers this shutdown.

Comment: It says the app "stops working" and then VB "is shutdown". Can you describe these events in more detail? Specific error messages / screenshots?

Comment: There is no message, so also no screenshot, it just stops working and shutdown everything, the running program and VB6.